# How do I find the hacker of my friend's account?

Tags: facebook

Someone hacked my friend's Facebook account and sent me messages which were indecent from his account.

He also commented stuff which were highly indecent on my pictures. How do I find out who hacked his account?

I asked my friend if it was him, but he said that his account had been hacked and thus couldn't do anything. I need to find the hacker of my friend's Facebook account and how do I do it?

Comment: If I were you, I wouldn't have very high hopes of finding the hacker.

Comment: You can delete the comments on your photos from your account and also I would contact facebook as they can take the account down and or recover it for your friend

Answer (score 2):

The "hacker" has done all actions from your "friend's" account, so all actions are attributed to your "friend" using their username/password. In other words, there's no way to find.